# Program to interfaces - how to access the calling class efficiently?

Tags: java, oop, interface, reference

I'm creating a genetic algorithm framework and I have a population class which includes a `Tournament` and an `EvolutionStrategy` object so that I can plug in different tournament types and evolution strategies.

Currently I have set it so that I create a new `EvolutionStrategy` object by passing in the `Population` object from population -

```
EvolutionStrategy strategy = new BasicStrategy(this);
```

In `BasicStrategy` constructor I have

```
Population pop;
public BasicStrategy(Population pop)
{
    this.pop = pop;
}
```

I have two questions regarding this

1) Does this create the proper reference variable, allowing updates to the population to be instantly accessible in the `EvolutionStrategy` or should I be using some form of synchronization ?

2) Is there a better way to do this? It seems wasteful to me to have a reference variable to the strategy in the `Population` and a reference variable to the population in the `Strategy`.

Comment: to 1) yes; java is pass by reference except for primitive types. 2) circular references are usually, but not always, a sign of bad design. In fact passing `this` in a constructor is very bad practice. But wasteful? What are you wasting?

Comment: Well I'm trying to focus on good design, maybe I phrased it incorrectly. Could you give an example of how to achieve this sort of modularity without using circular references?

Comment: Think about why the `Population` needs to know about the `EvolutionStrategy` and vice versa - do they really need to know about each other? Could you move the methods around? If the answers are "yes" followed by "no" then consider a class that knows about both of them and put the methods in there.

Comment: Well the evolutionstrategy needs access to modify the population so is what I'm doing the best approach? Basically what happens is that random individuals are mutated based on the evolutionstrategy and tournament type and scored based on a fitness function. The mutated individuals replace older individuals in the population.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. it is fine
2. I think that you should have one extra class like *EvolutionAlgorithm* in which you store *Population* (in terms of objects that are evolving) and *EvolutionStrategy* separately. When you want to evolve your population you just call evolutionStrategy's method with population as argument (Strategy Pattern). I think that evolutionStartegy doesn't need to store population. Also population can make sense without evolutionStrategy.

Comment: Thanks, I think bmorris had answered this but in the comments and I have just started to redesign using this suggestion. Now the problem is down to separating responsibilities in a logical manner but that's the fun of OOP ^.^